# How do I access a hash value that only exists in 1 attribute out of many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

So this one is a bit tricky.

I have an attribute that looks like this:

```
[22] pry(main)> n.media.meta_info[:response][:outputs]
=> [{"id"=>486,
  "url"=>"http://some-video.com/by-fire.mp4",
  "label"=>"webmp4",
  "state"=>"finished",
  "format"=>"mpeg4",
  "type"=>"standard",
  "frame_rate"=>30.06,
 {"id"=>488848287,
  "url"=>"http://some-video.com/by-fire.webm",
  "label"=>"webwebm",
  "state"=>"finished",
  "format"=>"webm",
  "type"=>"standard",
  "frame_rate"=>30.06,
 {"id"=>488848288,
  "url"=>"http://some-video.com/by-fire.ogv",
  "label"=>"webogv",
  "state"=>"finished",
  "format"=>"ogg",
  "type"=>"standard",
  "frame_rate"=>30.059,
 {"id"=>488848289,
  "url"=>
   "https://zencoder-temp-storage-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/",
  "label"=>nil,
  "state"=>"finished",
  "format"=>"mpeg4",
  "type"=>"standard",
  "frame_rate"=>30.06,
  "thumbnails"=>
   [{"label"=>nil,
     "images"=>
      [{"dimensions"=>"56x100",
        "file_size_bytes"=>15142,
        "format"=>"PNG",
        "url"=>"https://some-video.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/video/video_file/id/by-fire.png"}]}],
  "md5_checksum"=>nil}]
```

I am trying to access the `thumbnails` info, specifically the URL for the thumbnails.

I can't figure out how to get there though.

When I try to go the nested hash key of `thumbnails` it doesn't work:

```
[23] pry(main)> n.media.meta_info[:response][:outputs][:thumbnails]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
from (pry):22:in `[]'
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The hash you're showing isn't valid. Please show one that IRB will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[{` at the beginning of the output indicates that an array is returned. You first need to find a element in the array that contains a `thumbnails` key:

```
outputs = n.media.meta_info[:response][:outputs]
output_with_thumbnail = outputs.find { |elem| elem.keys.include?('thumbnails') }
```

Then continue like this:

```
output_with_thumbnail['thumbnails']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to find the thumbnail, and don't care about the rest of the outputs, you can use `#find` like so:

```
thumbnails = n.media.meta_info[:response][:outputs].find {|it| it[:thumbnails] }[:thumbnails]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of hashes, `thumbnails` are in the 3rd:

```
n.media.meta_info[:response][:outputs][3][:thumbnails]
```

Comment: This is awesome and fixes the issue for this specific hash, but I needed something more general for every other hash in my db.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

```
outputs = n.media.meta_info[:response][:outputs]
```

is an `Array` of hashes. So, you need to iterate over them first:

```
outputs.each do |output|
  # deal with each output here
end
```

You can check for `:thumbnails` like so:

```
if (thumbnails = output[:thumbnails])
  # we've got thumbnails, deal with it here
end
```